# Get everything after and before certain character in SQL

Tags: sql-server, substring

I have a string like

```
https:\/\/www.abc.ca\/v3\/homes\/190135717\/responses\/bulk?page=5&per_page=100
```

I want everything after the equal sign `=` and before `&`, i.e the number 5 in SQL Server

Comment: Have you looked at built-in functions in SQL Server like [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) and [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql)? What have you tried?

Comment: A simple Google search produces [this SQL function you could use](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=535E4591-CF78-4469-814C-B43291542B4B&tkw=query-string-parser-function). Have you tried something along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below logic using `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`:

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd77aa9f09a4d09c5c4a43d08d3fdd4b)

```
DECLARE @T VARCHAR(200) = 'https:\/\/www.abc.ca\/v3\/homes\/190135717\/responses\/bulk?page=5&per_page=100'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@T,CHARINDEX('=',@T,0)+1,CHARINDEX('&',@T,0)-CHARINDEX('=',@T,0)-1)
```

Comment: perfect thank you so much